# Is it necessary that an S3 bucket be in the same availability zone where an EC2 want to access it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it necessary that an S3 bucket be in the same availability zone where an EC2 want to access it?

Comment: No, but it makes it faster and cheaper (probably free).

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669611/cost-of-writing-and-reading1gb-file-into-an-s3-bucket

Answer (score 14):

S3 doesn't have availability zones, but it does have regions. And yes, having your bucket in the same region will make communication faster.

Comment: I think S3 files are stored in 3 different availability zones in the same region. So it is related to availability zones.

Comment: @Uri: I suppose a more accurate response is that Amazon does not expose availability zones for S3 to end users. Amazon only exposes regions for S3 to end users. Therefore it's not user-configurable.