# cost of writing and reading1GB file into an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What is the cost of writing and reading 1GB file into an S3 bucket from within an EC2 instance
in the same availability zone or in different availability zone?

Comment: Are you in the same availability zone?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this table which describes Amazon's pricing policy: http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/